# router is not working perfectly in react-router-dom-v6

Tags: reactjs

I m new to react and i am facing issues in react-router-dom(version-6)
When i try to route 3 files in app.js

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Services from './components/Services';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
// import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

// This is a React Router v6 app
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <Navbar />
      
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
          
        </Routes>
      
        
      {/* <About /> */}

      <Footer />

    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

i am getting only home page result only, other two(About, Services) things are not getting 
to resolve this issue what should i need to do? 
Please anyone help me from this 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rename BrowserRouter as Router and remove the div

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Link,
    Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom';


 function App() {

    return (
       <Router>
         <Navbar />
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
         </Routes>
         <Footer />
      </Router>
   );
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but i am getting any output

Comment: have you went to the other urls: loacalhost:3000/service, localhost:3000/about ?

Comment: Now i am getting correct result. I forgot to load localhost:3000/services, about. Now you  given good clarification on this. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: but i removed <Router></Router> tags then only i getting correct result. Please note this also.

Comment: do you have the <App/> wrapped by <BrowserRouter> in index.js?

Comment: Yes, i did this